# Magento 2 Error This page isn’t working is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento2

i used magento 2 but error as below

aryanorganics.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

tried to all previous stactoverflow answer still not work. 
please give me support

Answer (score 3):

As you tried it on Windows, it could come from this as well, as Windows is not case sensitive with files, and ubuntu is.

You should try looking at the server logs to have more information.

Or else put those lines in your index.php, it should show you the errors and help you debugging it (there is a developper mode you can enable in Magento but I prefere adding all those lines to get more informations) :

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```